# How Do I exit from TigerVNC vncviewer Full Screen Mode?

Tags: tigervnc

TigerVNC vncviewer has a popup menu if you press F8, but this does not work in Full Screen Mode.  Is there another way to exit full screen mode using vncviewer as provided by TigerVNC?

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F work?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F does not work.  I think that might be for other VNC projects.

Answer (score 2):

This is old but I just saw the issue ...

In tiger vnc hit f8 or function f8 if a laptop and a little menu should pop up . Uncheck Full screen ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to enable Full Screen Mode in the options for this to work properly.  When the option is enabled Full screen works, but the capturing of system keys sadly does not.  i.e. Alt-Tab